# Deathmatch map auto-switch not working

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Yesterday my friend and I played a CS:GO deathmatch in a Workshop map with some bots.
Then we kicked the bots out, and played a 1v1 sniper game. When the time stopped we were redirected to a new map and it was fun, but now the auto-switch isn't happening. After the time ended it said "New match starts in 5 seconds", but it didn't start!